Differences between systems engineering in the days of the Apollo program and in SpaceX
How was the approach to design different in the days of the Apollo program and today at SpaceX? I know that these are two different things that are difficult to compare. In any case, in both cases they quickly achieved admirable results.

You might be interested in the 1971 NASA paper "What Made Apollo a Success?" https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19720005243/downloads/19720005243.pdf

Apollo was breaking new ground in everything it did whereas SpaceX is built on the experience of people like Tom Mueller (Merlin engine designer with 15 years experience managing propulsion at TRW) and the DC-X vertical take-off & landing rocket, etc. etc.
